# sum data from multiple relation in multiple relation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-relations

I have a User model, who hasMany categories and category hasMany posts and post hasOne Product

Now I want to sum all of the product->price of **`Auth::user()`**

how can i do that `withSum` or `withCount` function. in Laravel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your question doesnt present any details, I will assume that you have all the relations well set up.

You can get the sum using the relations like this

```
$sum = Product::query()
           ->whereHas('post', function($post) {
               $post->whereHas('category', function($category) {
                   $category->whereHas('user', function($user) {
                       $user->where('id',auth()->id());
                   });
               });
           })
           ->sum('price');
```

Comment: I think you can also do `whereHas('post.category.user', function ($user) { $user->where('id', auth()->id()); })`